# Swift - Why is argument item in NSOutlineView always nil?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, delegates, nsobject

I am attempting to implement a simple sourceView, however, I am only managing to set the stringValue of one textField.

First, this is the structure of my program:

```
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController, NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSOutlineViewDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var sourceView: NSOutlineView!
    override func windowDidLoad()
    {
        sourceView.setDataSource(self)
        sourceView.setDelegate(self)
    }
}
```

Then, I have:

```
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: AnyObject?) -> Int 
{...}
```

And finally,:

```
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject
{...}
```

My issue is that in both of these functions, the value of item is nil. Is this what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear you're providing the object value. Unless you're using an NSTreeController to populate your NSOutlineView, you must also implement the data source function:

```
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, byItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {

    // return your object value
}
```

Comment: Is that analogous to viewForTableColum?

Comment: No, it's not the same at all. viewForTableColumn returns a view — objectValueForTableColumn returns the view's represented object. How are you supplying the data for your sourceView?